# Executing multiple Celery workers to consume unique queues

Tags: python, multithreading, celery, message-queue

I have a use case where I need to start a celery workers such that they consume unique queues, which I have tried to implement like following.

```
from celery import Celery

app = Celery(broker='redis://localhost:9555/0')


@app.task
def afunction(arg1=None, arg2=None, arg3=None):

    if arg1 == 'awesome_1':
        return "First type of Queue executed"
    if arg2 == "awesome_2":
        return "Second Type of Queue executed"
    if arg3 == "awesome_3":
        return "Third Type of Queue executed"


if __name__=='__main__':
    qlist = ["awesome_1", "awesome_2", "awesome_3"]
    arglist = [None, None, None]
    for q in qlist:
        arglist[qlist.index(q)] = q
        argv = [
            'worker',
            '--detach',
            '--queue={0}'.format(q),
            '--concurrency=1',
            '-E',
            '--loglevel=INFO'
        ]
        app.worker_main(argv)
        afunction.apply_async(args=[arglist[0], arglist[1], arglist[2]], queue=q)
```

This code upon execution gives the following output:

```
[2018-02-08 11:28:43,479: INFO/MainProcess] Connected to redis://localhost:9555/0
[2018-02-08 11:28:43,486: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: searching for neighbors
[2018-02-08 11:28:44,503: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: all alone
[2018-02-08 11:28:44,527: INFO/MainProcess] celery@SYSTEM ready.
[2018-02-08 11:28:44,612: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: __main__.afunction[f092f721-6523-4055-98fc-158ac316f4cc]
[2018-02-08 11:28:44,618: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-1] Task __main__.afunction[f092f721-6523-4055-98fc-158ac316f4cc] succeeded in 0.0010992150055244565s: 'First type of Queue executed'
```

Hence I can see the worker executing as it should for first iteration of the `for` loop, but then it stops right there and doesn't continue with the for loop.

I believe this is happening because worker is not running detached, or as subprocess of the script because I can see 1 + as many processes with python running the same script on `ps aux` as the `--concurrency` is being set. Any pointers on what is going wrong or how to make the worker queue run detached so after `return` that `for` loop continues iterating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to do the following workaround which gave the result as expected though I am unsure of infrastructural repercussions of the code. It would be great if someone can comment if there are better ways of solving the issue,but for now I am using this solution.

```
from celery import Celery
import os
import time


app = Celery('app', broker='redis://localhost:9555/0')

@app.task
def afunction(arg1=None, arg2=None, arg3=None):

    if arg1 == 'awesome_1':
        return "First type of Queue executed"
    if arg2 == "awesome_2":
        return "Second Type of Queue executed"
    if arg3 == "awesome_3":
        return "Third Type of Queue executed"

qlist = ["awesome_1", "awesome_2", "awesome_3"]
arglist = [None, None, None]
for q in qlist:
    os.system('nohup celery worker -A app.celery -Q {0} --loglevel=INFO --concurrency=1 &'.format(q))
    os.system('echo \'\\n\'')

time.sleep(5)
for q in qlist:
    arglist = [None, None, None]
    arglist[qlist.index(q)] = q
    afunction.apply_async(args=[arglist[0], arglist[1], arglist[2]], queue=q)
```

which created a nohup.out file with the following output:

```
[2018-02-08 17:15:53,269: INFO/MainProcess] Connected to redis://localhost:9555/0
[2018-02-08 17:15:53,272: INFO/MainProcess] Connected to redis://localhost:9555/0
[2018-02-08 17:15:53,274: INFO/MainProcess] Connected to redis://localhost:9555/0
[2018-02-08 17:15:53,277: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: searching for neighbors
[2018-02-08 17:15:53,280: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: searching for neighbors
[2018-02-08 17:15:53,280: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: searching for neighbors
[2018-02-08 17:15:54,293: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: all alone
[2018-02-08 17:15:54,295: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: all alone
[2018-02-08 17:15:54,296: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: all alone
[2018-02-08 17:15:54,304: INFO/MainProcess] celery@SYSTEM ready.
[2018-02-08 17:15:54,304: INFO/MainProcess] celery@SYSTEM ready.
[2018-02-08 17:15:54,306: INFO/MainProcess] celery@SYSTEM ready.
[2018-02-08 17:15:57,975: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: app.afunction[e825444d-e123-4f55-9365-f36f95d62734]
[2018-02-08 17:15:57,976: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-1] Task app.afunction[e825444d-e123-4f55-9365-f36f95d62734] succeeded in 0.0003634110325947404s: 'First type of Queue executed'
[2018-02-08 17:15:57,976: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: app.afunction[80816d50-5680-4373-8b5e-dac2ae2a3ff9]
[2018-02-08 17:15:57,977: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: app.afunction[0e88c758-3010-4d37-bda2-6a9a9a02bedf]
[2018-02-08 17:15:57,977: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-1] Task app.afunction[80816d50-5680-4373-8b5e-dac2ae2a3ff9] succeeded in 0.0003187900292687118s: 'Second Type of Queue executed'
[2018-02-08 17:15:57,978: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-1] Task app.afunction[0e88c758-3010-4d37-bda2-6a9a9a02bedf] succeeded in 0.00042019598186016083s: 'Third type of queue executed'
```